# Appending image in collectionView using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am new for Ios app development. I am using AFNetworking for image and data load, data are binned in collection view but unable to bind image.
This is my code for collection view and service:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LabelCollectionViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *idArray;
    NSMutableArray *namelabelArray;
    UIImage *imagArray;
    NSMutableArray *dic ;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self userCollection]setDataSource:self];
    [[self userCollection]setDelegate:self];
    [self dataJson];
    NSLog(@"array: %@", namelabelArray);  
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [namelabelArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    LabelCollectionViewCell *customCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    [[customCell nameLabel]setText:[namelabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [[customCell idLabel]setText:[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return customCell;   
}

-(void)dataJson
{
    NSString *zipcode;
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://inveera.biz/lowkall_api/index.php/product_cat"];
    NSDictionary *params =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: zipcode,@"35005",nil];
    NSLog(@"Login URL %@", params);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation      *operation, id responseObject) {  
        NSLog(@"Login JSON: %@", responseObject);
        NSString *data = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];
        idArray = [data valueForKey:@"id"];
        namelabelArray =[data valueForKey:@"name"];
        imagArray =[data valueForKey:@"img_path"];
        NSLog(@"Error image: %@", imagArray);
        [self.userCollection reloadData];
    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

My json response is

```
{
    "status":"true",
    "city":[{"cityname":"Acmar"}],
    "data":[
     {"id":"1","name":"Appliances","img_path":"categories\/1\/ac1.png","status":"1"},
     {"id":"2","name":"Electronics","img_path":"categories\/2\/ac2.png","status":"1"},
     {"id":"3","name":"Furniture","img_path":"categories\/3\/ac3.png","status":"1"},
     {"id":"4","name":"Cars","img_path":"categories\/4\/ac4.png","status":"1"},
     {"id":"5","name":"Pet Supplies","img_path":"categories\/5\/ac5.png","status":"1"},
     {"id":"6","name":"Others","img_path":"categories\/6\/ac6.png","status":"1"}
    ]
}
```

I am able to bind name but unable to bind image with full path with domain
name.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of `UIImage *imageArray;` it should be `NSString *imageURLString;`

and then since you are using AFNetworking better to load images async (use `#import UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`).

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.baseURL, imageURLString]];

[self setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL]
            placeholderImage:placeholder
                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        if (image)
        {
            weakSelf.image = image;
        }
 } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In AFNetworking Lib itself they have added one category class for UIImageView called UIImageView+AFNetworking to load images from URL, You need call below method with valid URL request.

```
 - (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                  placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                           success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                           failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure

-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    LabelCollectionViewCell *customCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    [[customCell nameLabel]setText:[namelabelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [[customCell idLabel]setText:[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];  
    [[customCell imageView] setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]
                          placeholderImage:nil
                                   success:nil
                                   failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                                   }];
    return customCell; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry Narayana but i am unable to do it. Can you please give me any demo like for json binding in collectionView or give code please

Comment: I have used This Code properly I am Not Getting I am loading Image On collection View Cell But Parameter Getting error Can you Plaese sent me Proper Afnetworking data load On Collection view (Actuaaly all Parameter Passing In Diffrent different Array I just Want to Proper array And Load With dictionary With Parameter ) Plazease Shere me

Comment: city =     (
                {
            cityname = "<null>";
        }
    );
  
2015-12-16 12:25:11.353 LowKall Apps[2563:49732] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f997ad63a90
2015-12-16 12:25:11.391 LowKall Apps[2563:49732] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f997ad63a90'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @Udaikumar can you please send your cellForItemAtIndexPath code here